# What am I supposed to do with blanks before each contract paragraph?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, contracts

I received an internship contract formatted in a way I have never seen before, and I wonder how am I supposed to sign it. There is a special place at the end for my signature, but strangely each paragraph starts with blanks, as if I was required to enter something there. It looks more or less like this:

```
   I understand the following:
    _____ I may blah blah blah
    _____ I should not blah blah blah
```

What am I supposed to enter into those blanks?

Comment: Why don't you email your question to those who sent you the forms?

Comment: Time to pull out the 'ol check mark: ✓. Additionally, a lot of times those just require initials ^^.

Comment: looks like some odd formatting error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd ask if this is to be filled in with words, signed with your initials, signed with your name, checked off or something else as each could make sense there.

Some places may want initials or name so that you can be identified as having known the piece. Check marks could be used as a way of noting that piece. There could also be that nothing is to be done unless you have a problem with some piece of it.